# Not all HTTPS requests from a loop reach server

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var lidd = 1;
        var ga1 = document.createElement('script'); ga1.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga1.async = true;           
        var res = ["A1LpRTPOUKU%3d", "a8g%2bUPW0%2bck%3d", "ptb0PT3OMIc%3d", "8NzewxsG6Zc%3d"];
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            alert('mid=' + res[i]);
            ga1.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
            'http://') + 'localhost:59115/ui/trackconversion.aspx?cid=CAR9nmKJG1A%3d&mid=' + res[i] + '&lid=' + lidd;
            var s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s1.parentNode.insertBefore(ga1, s1);
        }
    })();                  
</script>
```

My issue is that the `for` loop is not working properly in this code. Here the length of `res` is 4, hence the loop should be executed 4 times, but in my code it's only executed partially. This means, when I execute the code, I get  `alert('mid=' + res[i]);` 4 times showing all the four values, i.e., `"A1LpRTPOUKU%3d"`, `"a8g%2bUPW0%2bck%3d"`, `"ptb0PT3OMIc%3d"`, and `"8NzewxsG6Zc%3d"`. But after that, my `trackconversion.aspx` is hit only once instead of getting hit 4 times.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *Side note*, instead of `alert`, you can use `console.log` and inspect with debug tools.

Comment: Please read [ask] for information on how to write a good question. The way it's written now, your question title is *extremely* uninformative.

Comment: Meta discussion about this question's title: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291905/user-posting-wrong-question-title-because-title-already-exists

Comment: @Joe: Meaningful but inaccurate is not really an improvement

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't fully understand the question (I try to avoid JavaScript) so I took what was posted in the question and extrapolated something out of it. It was certainly an improvement on "Error in my JavaScript" as it at least highlights the OP was expecting something to happen `x` times, but it only happened `y`.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, but it wasn't the loop that wasn't happening.  Which the question clearly said "I get `alert` 4 times showing all the four values".

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right, that was a "duhh" moment on my behalf, luckily you've edited further for more clarification, though I'm not sure the https/http thing is an accurate title either, especially given the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the document.createElement part in the for loop. What you're doing now is creating the script tag once, add it to the document, and then changing the src a couple of times.

This does not work as you intended, you must create a new script element for each src. Example:

```
(function () {
    var lidd = 1;        
    var res = ["A1LpRTPOUKU%3d", "a8g%2bUPW0%2bck%3d", "ptb0PT3OMIc%3d", "8NzewxsG6Zc%3d"];
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        var ga1 = document.createElement('script'); ga1.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga1.async = true;   
        alert('mid=' + res[i]);
        ga1.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
        'http://') + 'localhost:59115/ui/trackconversion.aspx?cid=CAR9nmKJG1A%3d&mid=' + res[i] + '&lid=' + lidd;
        var s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s1.parentNode.insertBefore(ga1, s1);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Not the script creation part, only the adding to document part. I edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: I added a code example that demonstrates how you should do it.